# Monospaced font isn't monospaced in Java

Tags: java, javafx, text, fonts, monospace

I wanted to set the [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) to a monospaced font. In the end, I chose [GT Pressura Mono Regular Regular](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/226f58ab113a6d821def90a7d6dc2427).

But, something about him was weird. I have found that the text isn't monospaced, although the differences in letter width are small.

I thought there was a problem with the font, but I tried other monospaced fonts (both downloaded and from windows) and the width never matches. What is the problem? I only use upper case letters for text.

Please help.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I am adding a code for better illustration.

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MonospacedText extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var textA = new Text("A");
        textA.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textA.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 100));
    
        var textB = new Text("B");
        textB.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textB.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 100));
    
        var textC = new Text("C");
        textC.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textC.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 100));
    
        var textD = new Text("D");
        textD.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textD.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 100));
    
        var textE = new Text("E");
        textE.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textE.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 100));
    
        var vbox = new VBox(textA, textB, textC, textD, textE);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

It can already be seen in the picture that the letters aren't the same width. In addition, when I add this code, it prints different values.

```
System.out.println(textA.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
System.out.println(textB.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
System.out.println(textC.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
System.out.println(textD.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
System.out.println(textE.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());

// 54.00390625
// 41.89453125
// 44.091796875
// 46.09375
// 36.279296875
```

Comment: How are you determining that the text isn’t mono spaced?

Comment: I added a code that shows it.

Comment: “Mono spaced” doesn’t mean that all the individual glyphs have the same visual width. It means that, when laid out, the distance between the start of one glyph and the start of the next is constant. I believe that if you measure the `LOGICAL` bounds, instead of the `VISUAL` bounds, you’ll see that they’re constant, and if you lay out the characters in a single text, each will occupy the same amount of horizontal space (using varying amounts of non-visual space to compensate for the different visual bounds of each letter).

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. Anyway, is there an easier way to get the `VISUAL` width of a letter, please? I mean, is it possible to calculate the `VISUAL` width of a letter in some way so that I don't have to find out the width of each letter separately?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely occurring because it is unable to find the font.

Please try running the below call before setting the text (or some common font your system supports).  Then try with your font-family.  If it is not finding any fonts, Java is not able to find the installed fonts.

```
System.out.println(Font.getFontNames("Consolas"));
```

The below works for me in Windows 10.

```
Label title = new Label("Testing");
title.setFont(Font.font("Consolas", FontWeight.THIN, 60));
title.setTextFill(Color.RED);
```

Comment: He wrote this `[Consolas, Consolas Bold, Consolas Bold Italic, Consolas Italic]`
And I added code that makes it easy to see.