# trying to loop array list and print out neately listed using String.format

Tags: java, javafx

I am using multiple array lists and want to display a neat list for the user to view from selected data.
As seen below, I tried to format the output but as you might have guessed it does not create neat rows as each input can vary in character length. Is there a way to either tell each part to start at a particular position or create a space dedicated to a certain amount of characters and right-aligned so the list is neat going down? Or is there a better way to do this?

I will add a for loop to spit out multiple lines on my list.

```
mainTextArea.appendText(String.format("%-10s%-40s%-40s%-10s%-20s\n", "ID", "Surgeon Name", "Support Staff Name", "Theatre No", "Booking Date"));
mainTextArea.appendText(String.format("----------------------------------------\n"));
mainTextArea.appendText(String.format("%-10s%-40s%-40s%-10s%-20s\n", surgeonId, surgeonName,staffName, theatreNo, formattedDate));
```

Comment: You probably want to start by setting the [Font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html) for `mainTextArea` to a [fixed width font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640682/monospaced-font-isnt-monospaced-in-java). After that, I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Then explain how you want your GUI to appear. Maybe you can post some kind of image that shows how you want your GUI to look.

Comment: See more Java string formatting in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and this [resource](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Comment: I did have a look some resources and can see they recommend "%-10s%-e0s" way which would mean left aligned 10 characters but they don't seam to aligne in my array even if I use the same format for each line.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a `TableView` for data like this?